# Excel: VBA Find & Add Text in Row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a VBA macro that will look at the first row of a sheet (considered headers) which will find text in each subsequent column and then add a row on top and if a text is found, add text above it. I'm new to VBA and been using the macro recorder to play around and so far I got this:

```
Sub textFind()

    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark2
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Rows("1:1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({""Description"",""ITEM #"",""Short Description""},R[1]C)),""Sku"","""")"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({""Product Name"",""Text"",""Short Description""},R[1]C)),""Name"","""")"
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(COUNT(SEARCH({""Description"",""Text"",""Short Description""},R[1]C)),""Description"","""")"
End Sub
```

My question is how would I be able to change the code to be able to find text for example, "Item #", "Product ID", "Product #" in the entire row instead of like in my code where it finds it in a specific cell. Thank you!

Edit: Added Image to hopefully clarify what I asking for.

[image: Sheet 1]
This is the result after running the code with the R[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pr9o8.png) edit.

[image: Sheet 1-CodeError]
This is the result after running the code again however, I have switched the "Item #" Column.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Comment: Can you post some sample data or a sample table? I don't quite follow what you're trying to do.

Comment: @BruceWayne Sorry for not being clear on what it is I am asking for. I have edited the question and provided two images. The first image is the result of running the VBA macro with the edit you suggested. The second image shows what I need solved. With my current code, it will only fully work if the text that it is searching for is in a specified cell that is defined in the code. However if for example, text "Item #" is in column B instead it won't add the text above it. I can go back and manually enter in the cell in the code however I need it to find and add text dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to keep your macro, but have your `Count(Search(` search the entire row, just change the `R[1]C` to `R[1]`.

Comment: Thank you, however this doesn't fully solve my problem. With my current code, it searches through row 1 and adds text in a predefined cell. How would I be able to have it done dynamically? Since not all A1 cells will have "ITEM #" in it, it might be in cell AZ1 for example.